# bit manipulation to specific subset

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation

Considering the following code snippet.

```cpp
    for (int state = 1; state < 1 << n; state ++ )
        if (state & 1)
            for (int t = state; t; t &= t - 1)
```

The first for-loop is to enumerate all subsets of n elements, but what subset does the `t` represent.

Comment: This is a compound assignment. `t &= t-1` is same as `t = t & t-1` which is a bitwise AND of `t` and `t-1`

Comment: @Gerhardh I know, this, but I'm confused about what subset does `t` represent.

Comment: Maybe you should first clarify what that term is meaning. If that is basically your question, you might try to do the calculations step by step by hand for some values.

Comment: This is something you need to understand from the context, which we don't have. We don't see any subsets, we see just a couple of integers.

Comment: What is done inside that inner loop? `t` will ultimately go to 0 after a few steps. But what is purpose of that all?

Comment: Do not tag both C and C++ except when asking about differences or interactions between the two languages. C and C++ provide different features, and using multiple tags makes it harder for future users of Stack Overflow to find answers they are looking for. Pick one language and delete the other tag.

Comment: This code is really bad from the readability perspective...

Comment: @EricPostpischil While true in general I don't think it makes a difference in this *specific* case – question could be answered identically in both languages and answers would look alike as well...

Comment: @Aconcagua: Regardless of what you think of the question in this specific case, it is policy, and for good reason. A question agnostic about C versus C++ can still be answered with code that is dependent on C or C++, with the result that somebody searching for C information may find a question tagged C with only a C++ answer. Or language issues may arise unexpectedly when some conversion rule or grammatical precedence or language feature arises.

Comment: @EugeneSh.   Bit-twiddling code tends to do that.

Comment: @EricPostpischil So if 1. answer is fine in *any* of the two languages, but no others and 2. one wants to attract experts of both languages – do you advocate for writing two separate, apart from tag identical questions then?

Comment: @Spencer But it can be written with different levels of readability too. This one is close to the lower one (lack of parentheses clarifying the intention and such).

Comment: @Aconcagua: I have informed you what policy is and why. If you want to discuss it further, meta.stackexchange.com is available.

Comment: @EugeneSh. If I don't understand how this clear out bits as is – how would I if there are parentheses added? Where do you miss them at all? If there's need for clarification (likely...) then here just a comment helps out I think...

Comment: @EugeneSh.  I'm on your side with regards to the need for extra parentheses, but there are people who hate them -- they think it communicates a lack of understanding of operator precedence.  Which IMO is a silly thing to worry about.

Comment: @Spencer Well, if writing code for you I'll do `(a * b) + c` then... Oh, maybe even better, `(((a) * (b)) + (c))`...

Comment: @Aconcagua Don't worry about the parentheses; it's not relevant to the question.  Actually, I think posting the full code was a mistake because it opened up too many opportunities for tangents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (int t = state; t; t &= t - 1)
```

This loop is removing the least-significant `1` bits from `t`, one by one.

So an initial value of `state` like 63 (binary `111111`) would go to 62 (`111110`), then 60, (`111100`),  56 (`111000`), 48 (`110000`), 32, (`100000`), and finally 0.